# Get border size for NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I'm setting a NSTextField height based on the size of a text with a fixed width.
If I set the NSTextField with no border, it gives me a correct measure. But if I changed the border style, it varies.
Is there a way to get the border size, or better yet, the content size of the NSTextField ?

Comment: Are you talking about the height of the texts in the NSTextField?

Comment: No, the height and width of the border. The height of the text I can calculate. But when NSTextField is bordered, I need to adjust the size height and width depending on the type of border. Otherwise the text gets clipped by the border